# jQuery .CSS opacity not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity

I wrote a short script in JS to mimic effect made in Flash.
It is working in `FF` 3.6, but it not working in `Chrome, Opera or IE8`.
Everything is working except `.css({opacity: opacity});`

Have I missed something? Thanks. edit: I was missing closing quote.

Live: http://webarto.com/static/demo/cubes/

```
var cubes = 16;

var x = cubes;
var y = cubes;
var n = 1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var cubes = $("#cubes");
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= y; j++) {
            cubes.append('<div id="cube_' + n + '"></div>');
            n++;
        }
    }

    setInterval(cube, 50);

});

function cube() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var opacity = Math.random() * 0.8;
    $("#cube_" + rand).css({
        opacity: opacity
    });
}
```

Thanks to @Gaby aka G. Petrioli for optimization.

Comment: The `cube` function seems to be working properly: http://jsbin.com/ozice4/2/edit -- Tested in Chrome and didn't see a problem.

Comment: @RussellUresti, it does work, but applying opacity doesn't. Please check live link http://webarto.com/static/demo/cubes/. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not close the id attribute of the dynamic elements, and that causes all browsers but FF to fail..

```
<div id="cube_' + n + '></div>
```

should be

```
<div id="cube_' + n + '"></div>
```

(*missing the `"` at the end of the id attribute*)

---

Additionally you should cache your `#cube` element instead of making jQuery find it for each iteration.

store a reference to it outside of your loop `var $cubes = $("#cubes");` and use that inside the loop `$cubes.append(...);`

Finally change the `setInterval` to not use a string but a direct reference to your function

```
setInterval(cube, 50);
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/yyrfW/2/

Comment: You have 2 syntax errors, first `var $cube`, and second `$cubes`.. best of all they are not cubes but squares :D

Answer (score 2):

jQuery opacity works cross browser. Your opacity script is working for me.

### Check http://jsfiddle.net/hwj6Q/

Comment: Yes, cube_1 - cube_256 exist.  They are created in the `ready()` handler.

Comment: Thank you for example. Yes, but rand returns 0-1 * 256, which is not out of bounds and elements exist. Could you check out my link and confirm it is working in Chrome?

Comment: I didn't see you had a link. I will check.

Comment: I forgot to close id attribute in HTML. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

for IE you have to use something similar as below

```
  filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
```

an example below

```
.change_opacity {
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
width: 100%; /* for IE */
}
```

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't jQuery handle that? Here's a link http://webarto.com/static/demo/cubes/

Comment: jQuery opacity works cross browser. No need to define any CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add something like moz-opacity webkit-opacity o-opacity etc. At least that's just a guess I'm a noob at this hopefully that helps at least a little.